# Why do watches seem to avoid firing when number is set to same value

Tags: angularjs, watch

I am trying to do something similar to [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9alU1uVPjsusMuOHsz6T). Notice that I use an ng-click event to set the value of the number back to the same number. However, the change does not seem to fire.

```
$scope.$watch('value', function(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log("Value changed from "+oldValue+" to "+newValue);
});
$scope.call = function(){
  console.log("Call is called");
  $scope.value=1;
}
```

So I change this to the following...

```
$scope.call = function(){
  console.log("Call is called");
  $scope.value=0;
  $scope.value=1;
}
```

Still no watch fire, however, [this will seem to solve the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/fELY2M7FXrKBMJqgQtcV) (albeit very in a messy way)

```
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.value = {};
$scope.value.value=1;
$scope.$watch('value', function(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log("Value changed from "+oldValue.value+" to "+newValue.value);
});
$scope.call = function(){
  console.log("Call is called");
  $scope.value = {};
  $scope.value.value=1;
}
```

So the question is, what is going on here and why can't I watch a number that is set to the same value? Is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: In browser console:
({field: '1'} == {field: '1'}) >> false
'1' == '1' >> true Add the answer to your question: $watch should be launched when value changed, so it avoids firing when number is set to same value -)

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work. Angular's `$watch` loop compares the current value with the old one and triggers your handler only if the value changed. When `$scope.value.value=1;` executes there's no "magic" behind telling Angular that you assigned a value to the variable being watched.

Comment: Furthermore there is an _experiemental_ new API implemented by a few browsers already that intends to eliminate the need for the whole `$watch` loop by providing a way to _observe_ changes to object properties (http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:observe). If you are on latest Chrome try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lspc2xx3/ - you'll see that this implementation does not trigger the change event if you don't  actually change the value.

Comment: Ok so if that is the way it works why does the one where I change the value not work?

Comment: Because you are watching `$scope.value`, not `$scope.value.value`, and `$scope.value` is an object. Comparing objects with `===` (what Angular does) is done by _reference_. When you assign `$scope.value = {};` you are essentially assigning a _new reference_ to `$scope.value`. A _new_ reference is obviously different (`!==`) than the old one so the `$watch` handler is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is [documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)(scroll down to $watch section)

> The listener is called only when the value from the current
>   watchExpression and the previous call to watchExpression are not equal
>   (with the exception of the initial run). 
>   Inequality is
>   determined according to reference inequality, strict comparison via
>   the !== Javascript operator, unless objectEquality == true ...

Comment: Right but check out my example where I change the value this still doesn't work. Is that because the digest is applied? I can't reapply because it will give me already applying error

Comment: @Jackie you are comparing objects(which are compared by reference)